# how to enable/ disable based on the select dropdown value using HTMLTable in jquery asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have read this [document](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) for better understanding to achieve my requirement I have tried this below code

using the below jquery scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <link rel="Stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
```

and I have commented the above scripts and used this as per [document](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) my logic enable or disable logic is not working but as show in the document example is working...

So suggest me which concept should I use to achieve this functionality.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
```

Dynamically adding the records to jquery table using this below code

```
function AddAutoTradePagerows() {

    $('#btnAdd').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //selectedinstrument: $('#AutoTradeTop_Instrument option:selected').text() 
        var paramsmbl = { entredsmbl: $('#search').val() };
        //alert(paramsmbl.entredsmbl);

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "AutoTrade.aspx/AutoFillData",
            data: JSON.stringify(paramsmbl),
            dataType: "json", 

            dataFilter: function (data) {

                return data;
            },

            success: function (data) {
               var ddlExitoptsdata = '';
              $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {

                    if (value.Type == "exitparameters") {

                        //Adding values to variable
                        ddlExitoptsdata += "<option>" + value.TypeData + "</option>";
                    }
                });
                 
//Calling method to fill the data
         AddTableRowsToTable(symbol, instrument, expdate, lotsize, delta, ltpliveamount, strikeprice, optionsdata, ddlExitoptsdata, ddlSToptsdata);

                
    },
            error: function ajaxError(data) {
                alert(data.status + ' : ' + data.statusText);
            }

        });

        

    })

}

function AddTableRowsToTable(initialsymbal, inst, exdate, lsize, delta, ltp, sprice, optionsdata, ddlExitoptsdata, ddlSToptsdata) {
   
//adding the dropdownlist ot variable
    var ddlExit = "<select class='exitselect' id='ddlexitauto' onchange='ddlexitchange(this.value);'>" + ddlExitoptsdata + "</select>";
  
        var trd = "";
        trd += "<tr>";
        trd += "<td>";
        trd += ddlExit; // dynamically adding the dropdownlist to jquery table 
        trd += "</td>";
        trd += "<td class='text-center txtdisable'><input type='text' id='EntryParameters_tgt' class='tabletwotextbox'> </td>";
        trd += "<td class='text-center txtdisable'><input type='text' id='EntryParameters_sl' class='tabletwotextbox'> </td>";
        trd += "<td class='text-center txtdisable'><input type='text' id='EntryParameters_tt' class='tabletwotextbox'> </td>";
        trd += "<td class='text-center txtdisable'><input type='text' id='EntryParameters_ts' class='tabletwotextbox'> </td>";
        trd += "</tr>";
        $("#EntryParametersTableRightDataID tbody").append(trd);

    }
  
}
```

I have created the `ddlexitchange(txt)` for which option I'm selecting based on that option the values should disable/enable.

```
function ddlexitchange(txt) {

//alert(txt);
 if (txt != undefined) {

           if (txt.toLowerCase() == "sq off leg") {
            //$("td:eq(2)").prop("disabled", true); //This functionality is not working

$("td:eq(2)").prop("disabled", true); //in this 2 place I want to pass the dynamic index value of textbox like show in image(textbox)

        }
        else {
            $("td:eq(2)").prop("disabled", false);
        }
}
```

And I have tried this logic , also not working well

```
       var currentrow = $(this).closest("tr");
        ////alert(currentrow);
        currentrow.find("td:eq(0)").prop("disabled", false);
        currentrow.find("td:eq(1)").prop("disabled", false);
```

And here I'm calling this `ddlexitchange(txt)` function at dropdown control `onchange='ddlexitchange(this.value);'`. By using this function the selected value is coming properly (at each row) .

Note :- My requirement is if I change any value in the drowdownlist based on the value `TextBox` will disable or enable in each row separately.

Example Image is :-

[image: Jquery table]

Above image tell us if I select `None` All `TextBox` should be in disabled mode(not editable) and if I select any other `TextBox` should be enable (at each row [ and we can add n number of rows ==> this is `JQueryTable`]).

Suggest me how can I achieve this dynamically.

Comment: If you'd read that page, you'd see it states: *As of jQuery 3.4, the `:eq` pseudo-class is deprecated. Remove it from your selectors*

Comment: Using `:eq` (for now), you *probably* want: `$("td:eq(2) *")` or `$("td:eq(2) input")` to disable the inputs in that `td` rather than the `td` itself.  Disabled property on a `td` has no effect on the inputs in that `td`.

Comment: We need more information about the debugging you've done: How are you calling the `ddlexitchange()` function? What value are you providing to `txt`? Is the `td:eq(2)` element found? Also seeing the HTML output (note *HTML output* **not** C# code) would help, as disabling a `td` isn't really going to do anything.

Comment: In what function are you running this code `var currentrow = $(this).closest("tr");`  ? Also it would be helpfull if you could include the relevant html

Comment: TBH - you've asked about `td:eq(2)` - but your problem has nothing to do with that selector.  You really should have done some *basic* debugging to determine which part is the actual problem.  eg `console.log($("td:eq(2).length)` - oh, that works...  then `$("td:eq(2)").css("background-color", "red")` - that works, so it's *clearly* not the td:eq that's the issue.

Comment: In one hand you give some detail on your code, but in the other we have no idea how the whole code is. It would really help us if you can minimise your example to the line that doesn't work, and give an html/js script that we can reproduce

Comment: @MisterAqua I have add the total code , suggest me how can I achieve this concept.

Comment: It would really help us if you can minimise your example to the line that doesn't work, all the AJAX and dynamic tablerows make it hard to understand (also please add some comments)

Comment: @MisterAqua thanks for your patients I have modified my post content may be this will help you for better understand (I'm new to jquery logics please help me )

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for your comment, if not effect any input in `td` how can I achieve this and which concept should I apply here please suggest my I'm new to jquery logics

Comment: As in my comment above `$("td:eq(2) input")` will select all inputs in the 3rd td.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have passed  like this `$("td:eq(2) input").prop("disabled", false);` but it is not working well I used this script  `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>` .  is this logic will work in `JQueryTable' ? plase help me

Comment: What's `jQueryTable`?

Comment: @freedomn-m I have created table and  adding fields dynamically please once check the above code method name is `AddTableRowsToTable` In this method I'm adding the `dropdown list` and `textbox` fields from here I'm calling the `onchange='ddlexitchange(this.value);'` functions so this `$("td:eq(2) input").prop("disabled", false);` logic will work in this scenario that is my question please suggest me.